# logical error in python snake game

Tags: python

I'm training on a snake game in python and can't get a function to return expected results. It seems to be a logical error but I can't figure this out

Here is the function:

```
    def food(zone, meat, snake):
    ''' Returns an (x, y) tuple if there is a location for a new apple
    available. Otherwise returns None '''

    if len(meat) >= zone.height * zone.width - len(snake):
        return None

    x = random.randrange(0, zone.width)
    y = random.randrange(0, zone.height)

    position_free = True

    for rib in meat:
        if rib[0] == x and rib[1] == y:
            position_free = False

    for part in snake:
        if part[0] == x and part[1] == y:
            position_free = False

    if position_free and not zone.is_out_of_bounds(x, y):
        meat.append((x, y))
    else:
        return food(zone, meat, snake)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code, where you are calling this 'food' function?

Comment: The most important tag you need here is Python, not only snakes

Comment: add many `print()` to see what is going on in this function.

Comment: you add `(x,y)` to `apple` but you don't return it.

Answer (score 0):

> Returns an (x, y) tuple

The return statement doesn't seem to return an x,y tuple at all - and there's a way out of the function without returning anything. `apples.append((x, y))` and then quit.

I don't know how often you call `food()` but it doesn't look like that will work properly. What the code does:

- Pick a single space at random
- If there's no snake or meat in that spot (it could have an apple `:D` ):

  - Store that one location in a list and quit without returning anything (oh `:(` ).
- If there is snake or meat in that spot (it can't have an apple `:(`):

  - Put an apple in a place found during a previous `food()` call, which is possibly no longer accurate because the snake will have moved since then, or the list may be empty since it only checked one random space last time.

What the description says it will do is more like:

- Try as many spaces as necessary, ultimately checking every single space in the zone
- Identify all the free spaces (no snake, no meat)
- Pick one of those at random and return it (you don't say that, but it makes sense to randomise it, otherwise the apples would appear always in the top-leftmost corner, or wherever you searched first)
- if there are no free spaces after checking every space, return None

That would look more like this (untested example code):

```python
def food(zone, meat, snake):
    ''' Returns an (x, y) tuple if there is a location for a new apple
    available. Otherwise returns None '''

    import random
    free_spaces = []

    for x in range(zone.width):
        for y in range(zone.height):
            if (x, y) not in snake and (x, y) not in meat:
                   free_spaces.append((x, y))        

    if free_spaces:        
        return random.choice(free_spaces)

    return None
```

The `(x,y) not in snake` test will work if the snake is a list of tuples, like `[(4,6), (5,6), (5,7)]`, but it might not work otherwise.

Comment: I got rid of apples and kept rib from meat. sorry about this and not sure I understand your comments well. I need to spend time on it. Thanks for your help

Comment: would something like this make sense? `if position_free and not game_area.is_out_of_bounds(x, y):
            apples.append((x, y))
            return new_apple_loc(game_area, apples, snake)
        else:
            return None`

Comment: @toto - Does that make sense?  It's readable, but it doesn't do what your description says the function will do. If you only test one place, you aren't doing what your description says *"is there is a location for a new apple available"*, you might hit a snake, but there's still room for an apple somewhere else. - but you haven't explained what your function is supposed to do, or what `new_apple_loc()` does, what the `apples` list represents, or how you are using `food()` in your program, so I can't really say. I rewrote it in a way that makes sense to me, but I might be misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm sorry this is an exercise I don't have the entire program. I think that it should return the location of apples if that location is available. if not it should return None. At least that's what I thought now I'm confused

Comment: @toto *"the location of apples, if that location is available"* is too vague to translate into code. The function doesn't take location or apples as parameters, so ... what location? which apples? The description says "a location", so I guess anywhere on the board, for "a new apple", one apple, not a pre-existing one. That reads to me like the function returns the location of an empty space, or nothing if there are no empty spaces.